# How to encrypt a PDF file on macOS programmatically

Tags: macos, pdf, encryption

My software generates PDF files using the built-in APIs (PDFKit).

I now need to create a password protected (through encryption) PDF file from it, programmatically. PDFKit does not seem to support that.

*I had hoped that I could use AppleScript to tell Preview to open the PDF and then save it with a password, but it appears that Preview's AppleScript dictionary does not provide an option for that.*

What are my options?

Comment: Do you specifically need PDF encryption (the one that gives the "password" input field in Preview) or would you be ok encrypting/decrypting the file with something like PGP?

Comment: If you don't want to rewrite your document you could compile an existing solution such as [this one (VersyPDF, just Googled it)](https://github.com/sybrexsys/VersyPDF) and save using PDFKit / load / encrypt / save. Disadvantage is the temporary unencrypted intermediate file of course. If possible use memory storage or otherwise protected storage. Another disadvantage may be additional memory and processor usage, but hey, maybe you've got plenty. Just thinking along here.

Comment: It seems I need to clarify why I need to encrypt the PDF file: So that I can send it over email to someone else who can then easily decrypt it with the shared password, without special software (such as PGP). Having temporarily an unencrypted PDF on the originating computer is not an issue, or I'd have not mentioned the AppleScript method. Thanks for the pointer to VersyPDF. If you'd make an answer out of that, that would be more useful to everyone than a comment, I think.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're already familiar with Apple's PDFKit APIs, then encrypting a PDF is very easy.

Create an Auxiliary Dictionary with key/values for items like `kCGPDFContextOwnerPassword` and `kCGPDFContextAllowsCopying`. Then use `PDFDocument`'s `writeToFile:withOptions` method.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/pdfkit/pdfdocument/1436053-writetofile?language=objc

Here's a python script that will encrypt PDFs, but it should be very easy to translate this into Swift or ObjC. The dictionary is named '`options`'.

On the command line, supply filenames of PDFs as arguments. You can also use this in an Automator "Run Shell Script" action.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# coding: utf-8

import os, sys
from Quartz import PDFDocument, kCGPDFContextAllowsCopying, kCGPDFContextAllowsPrinting, kCGPDFContextUserPassword, kCGPDFContextOwnerPassword
from CoreFoundation import (NSURL)

copyPassword = "12345678" # Password for copying and printing
openPassword = copyPassword # Password to open the file.
# Set openPassword as '' to allow opening with no password.

def encrypt(filename):
    filename =filename.decode('utf-8')
    if not filename:
        print 'Unable to open input file'
        sys.exit(2)
    shortName = os.path.splitext(filename)[0]
    outputfile = shortName+" locked.pdf"
    pdfURL = NSURL.fileURLWithPath_(filename)
    pdfDoc = PDFDocument.alloc().initWithURL_(pdfURL)
    if pdfDoc :
        options = { 
            kCGPDFContextAllowsCopying: False, 
            kCGPDFContextAllowsPrinting: False, 
            kCGPDFContextOwnerPassword: copyPassword,
            kCGPDFContextUserPassword: openPassword}
        pdfDoc.writeToFile_withOptions_(outputfile, options)
    return

if __name__ == "__main__":
    for filename in sys.argv[1:]:
        encrypt(filename)
```